# Passing Angular variable to Express backend through POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

`req.body` is always empty.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?  I tried adding content-type headers as json but that didn't do anything either.  Can someone lead me in the correct direction please?  Thank you

EDIT: just for clarification purposes, my Angular frontend hits the backend function successfully, but req.body is empty.  If I understand everything correctly, if I'm using the 'body-parser' library, it should be passed in through post through 'req.body'.  I'm just not seeing that though and I'm not sure why.

EDIT2: I have the body parser code in my app.js but the backend routing in a index.js file, does that have anything to do with it?

EDIT3: app.js http://pastebin.com/9vNgf0Nd
index.js http://pastebin.com/icLa3e2X

ANGULAR FRONTEND

```
service.registerAccount = function(account) {
        console.log(account);  //account = { userName: 'test', password: 'hello' }
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/register',
            data: { account: account },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        });
    }
```

BACKEND (app.js)

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

BACKEND (index.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();    

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
};
```

Comment: Have you tried a direct call to the REST service? Using RESTClient, Postman or something like that.

Comment: @CarlosLaspina no i haven't.  i guess i can look into doing that right now..

Comment: It would be helpful to know in which layer the problem occurs

Comment: @CarlosLaspina so i tried it on a REST console but it's just doing the same thing?  i'm not sure what i'm supposed to be looking for here

Comment: If for example, when making a post request to your URL, http://localhost:8080/register, does everything that is supposed to do we would know that the problem goes through the call, otherwise the problem lies in the backend. I hope I was clear.

Comment: @CarlosLaspina i mean.. it's still the same as the original question as I'm asking.  It goes into the backend successfully, I'm just not sure where or how to grab the data.  From what I've been researching, if I've done it properly it should be in the req.body due to the body-parser library i'm using... but I don't see it and I don't understand why.

Comment: What version of node are you running? Check by executing `node -v`

Comment: @MosheKarmel v4.6.0

Comment: Can you show how  `router` variable is defined ?

Comment: FYI - your client side code is ok. There is nothing worng

Comment: @bhantol okay hm.  i just edited the OP about having the body parser code in app.js but my routing in index.js.. but i dont declare any body parser code in the index.js, could that be it?

Comment: Can you try to use just app.use(bodyParser());, just for testing?

Comment: @AnthonyC hey AnthonyC, i just tried it and still same thing unfortunately

Comment: We need to see the `router`

Comment: @bhantol edited the OP with my full code for app.js and index.js

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access pastebins here behind the firewall - try my answer. Or just show where router is defined.

Comment: @bhantol i edited OP to show you where router is defined.  gonna look at your answer right now

Comment: Updated my answer based on your information - pastebin (I had to access from my phone) You are missing `app.use(router)` which tells express that it will be using routers to handle the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove this line

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Also,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

have to be called before `app.use('/', routes);`

And make sure to add Content-Type: application/json to the request header

Comment: just tried it, it says that body-parser is deprecated but it still ran anyway, but unfortunately i got the same results.  ty for trying though

Comment: with the `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` removed?

Comment: Can you try to change the line order as well?`app.use(bodyParser.json());` has to be called before 
`app.use('/', routes);`

Comment: YOUR LAST COMMENT WORKED !  TYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

Comment: oh and i didn't have to remove the bodyParser.urlencoded.  that was actually default code from the express-generator

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add the content type?

```
service.registerAccount = function(account) {
        console.log(account);  //account = { userName: 'test', password: 'hello' }
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/register',
            data: { account: account },
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: same thing unfortunately!  =T

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the UI code. Not sure what is `router` so you may try this or post the code for router.

Try this (this works for me) or you can also use your router:

```
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.account.username)

});
```

You are missing:

```
var app = express();
app.use(router);
```

If you want to user routers refers to following example:

UPDATE with full code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();    
var app = express();
app.use(router);
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
};
app.route('/register')
  .post(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.account.username)
  })
```

Comment: do i add 'app.use(router)' to my app.js?   edit: wait that doesnt' make sense because i define var router = express.Router() in my index.js.  so should i define it there by saying 'express.use(router)'?

Comment: Add to your index.js

Comment: it says 'app is not defined'  and if i try express.use it says 'express.use is not a function'.  do i have to define 'var app = express()' again in my index.js?

Comment: Use `var app = express();` before `app.use(router);`

Comment: Add the 2 lines right after 'var router = express.Router()`. You can read some quick starts http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

Comment: still says same thing unfortunately =[

Comment: Try the full code I gave from `var express......` If you still get `express` not defined then you are missing npm module express. For that do this `npm install express --save` in the same folder where you have your index.js.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

and then execute this from prompt:

```
$ curl localhost:8081/register -v --data "{\"name\":\"test\",\"password\":\"hello\"}" --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

this works for me!

Comment: hm same thing unfortunatley adlfkjadslkfjasdf